# Spring Boot Test @ConfigurationProperties does not bind fields

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-test

Good evening everyone. I have a class that is designed for binding with properties. In the class labeled `@Configuration`, I make this bean object like:

```java
// Into TargetConfiguration class

@Bean("someBeanName")
@ConfigurationProperties("some.path")
public beanProperties() {
    return new BeanProperties();
}
```

I would like to test all the functionality of this configuration and for this I create a test class like:

```java
@WebFluxTest
@TestPropertySource("classpath:test.properties")
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {TargetConfiguration.class})
class Test {...}
```

The problem is that `BeanProperties` will contain null fields, but if I make some other`OtherBeanProperties` and register it via `@EnableConfigurationProperties` in`TargetConfiguration`, then it will be normally filled, but for `BeanProperties` I can’t do this, since this bean depends on the property in *test.properties*. Also if I create this bean through the `@TestConfiguration` configuration, then it will be filled to...

Any help is appreciated.

**UPD-1:** The first assumption - I register some class which extends `BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor` with `@DependsOn` annotation named `RegistratorClass`. I don't know why, but if i add `@DependsOn` on `RegistratorClass` class, my `BeanProperties` immediately constructed without binding (And passing to other method which want to receiver this `BeanProperties`). If i remove this annotation, `RegistratorClass` initialized the first and my `BeanProperties` will be normally constructed and bound to properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor` is initialized early in the lifecycle and is intended to be used to add additional bean definitions. In the example code that you posted at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/21584 you are declaring that `beanGenerator` depends on `someOtherBeanUser`. In turn, `someOtherBeanUser` injects `beanUser`. This means that `someOtherBeanUser` and `beanUser` are injected very early.

The way configuration binding works is via the `ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor`. By triggering early initialization you're forcing Spring to create `beanUser` before the `ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor` has been registered. This means that no binding can be applied.

A complete sample application would help determine why your properties are not being bound, but I believe that adding `@EnableConfigurationProperties` to `TargetConfiguration` or the test class itself will fix it.

Comment: `@EnableConfigurationProperties` still not works if i don't remove `@DependsOn` on `ClassExtendsBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor`. But removing `@DependsOn` is more convenient, because i don't know that Spring will be initialize `ClassExtendsBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor` early.

Comment: I will accept one part of this answer (About `@BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor`),  but the second part is not workable for my. My be it will a new question. Thanks